# R Loop with conditions

Tags: r, loops, if-statement, while-loop

I have a series of repeated IDs that I would like to assign to groups with fix size. The subject IDs repeat with different frequencies for example:

```
# Example Data 
ID = c(101,102,103,104)
Repeats = c(2,3,1,3)
Data = data.frame(ID,Repeats)
> head(Data)
   ID Repeats
1 101       2
2 102       3
3 103       1
4 104       3
```

I would like the same repeated ID to stay within the same group. However, each group has a fixed capacity (say 3 only). For example, in my desired output matrix each group can only accommodate 3 IDs:

```
# Create empty data frame for group annotation
# Add 3 rows in order to have more space for IDs
# Some groups will have NAs due to  keeping IDs together (I'm OK with that)
Target = data.frame(matrix(NA,nrow=(sum(Data$Repeats)+3),
                                   ncol=dim(Data)[2]))
names(Target)<-c("ID","Group")
Target$Group<-rep(1:3)
Target$Group<-sort(Target$Group)
> head(Target)
  ID Group
1 NA     1
2 NA     1
3 NA     1
4 NA     1
5 NA     2
6 NA     2
```

I can loop each ID to my Target data frame but this does not guarantee that repeated IDs will stay together in the same group:

```
# Loop repeated IDs the groups 
IDs.repeat = rep(Data$ID, times=Data$Repeats)
# loop IDs to Targets to assign IDs to groups
for (i in 1:length(IDs.repeat))
{
  Target$ID[i]<-IDs.repeat[i]
}
```

In my example in the loop above I get the same ID (102) across two different groups (1 and 2), I would like to avoid this!:

```
> head(Target)
   ID Group
1 101     1
2 101     1
3 102     1
4 102     1
5 102     2
6 103     2
```

Instead I want the output to look the code to put NA if there is no space for that ID in that group.

```
> head(Target)
   ID Group
1 101     1
2 101     1
3  NA     1
4  NA     1
5 102     2
6 102     2
```

Anyone has a solution for IDs to stay within the same group if there is sufficient space after assigning ID i?

I think that I need a loop and count NAs within that group and see if the NAs>= to the length of that unique ID. However, I don't know how to implement this simultaneously. Maybe nesting another loop for the j group?

Any help with the loop will be appreciated immensely!

Answer (score 0):

Here's one solution,

```
## This is the data.frame I'll try to match
target <- data.frame(
  ID = c(
    rep(101, 2),
    rep(102, 3),
    rep(103, 1),
    rep(104, 3)),
  Group = c(
    rep(1L, 6), # "L", like 1L makes it an int type rather than numeric
    rep(2L, 3)
  )
)
print(target)

## Your example data
ID = c(101,102,103,104)
Repeats = c(2,3,1,3)
Data = data.frame(ID,Repeats)
head(Data)


ids_to_group <- 3 # the number of ids per group is specified here.
Data$Group <- sort(
  rep(1:ceiling(length(Data$ID) / ids_to_group),
      ids_to_group))[1:length(Data$ID)]

# The do.call(rbind, lapply(x = a series, FUN = function(x) { }))
# pattern is a really useful way to stack data.frames
# lapply is basically a fancy for-loop check it out by sending
# ?lapply to the console (to view the help page).
output <- do.call(
  rbind,
  lapply(unique(Data$ID), FUN = function(ids) {
    print(paste(ids, "done.")) # I like to put print statements to follow along
    obs <- Data[Data$ID == ids, ]
    data.frame(ID = rep(obs$ID, obs$Repeats))
  })
)

output <- merge(output, Data[,c("ID", "Group")], by = "ID")

identical(target, output) # returns true if they're equivalent

# For example inspect each with:
str(target)
str(output)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. This approach is interesting and might be a solution. However, in your example the object output groups more than 3 IDs per group (from your code above):                                                             `> print(output)
   ID Group
1 101     1
2 101     1
3 102     1
4 102     1
5 102     1
6 103     1
7 104     2
8 104     2
9 104     2`

Comment: Hmm, I might be misunderstanding. The output you printed shows ids 101, 102, and 103 labeled as group 1, and 104 (the fourth unique id) beginning group 2. Four ids, at most three in each group yields two groups.

Comment: Thank you for following up. That's exactly what I'm trying to avoid. I don't want the same ID in different groups. I would like for each ID to be in a single group. However, this is difficult because each ID repeats different amount of times. If you print(output) in your example you can see that there are 6 IDs in group 1. I'm OK having NAs if the ID is longer than the number of groups available.

Comment: Ah, now I understand. That should be possible by changing the line `ids_to_group <- 3` to `ids_to_group <- 1`.

Comment: Thanks! Although that codes assigns each ID to a group. I'm OK having different IDs per group (I actually need to have a mix of IDs per group) However, I'm limited in the number of spots per group (i.e. 4 spots per group) and the number of IDs differ. So in my example above 101 fits in group 1 leaving only two spots open and therefore 102 with 3 repeats needs to go into a different group.

Comment: Hmm, I think I understand. Group sizes are fixed. Do you mind editing the existing question for clarity and simplicity? For example, what if an ID is repeated more than four times (group size)? Also, if I might ask, what's the motivation for this particular data.frame structure? There might be a more suitable structure.

Comment: Yes, group size is fixed at 3 always for every single group. IDs can repeat with varying frequencies (once, twice or three times). I have edited the example above. The motivation is an experimental design with different number of replicates (i.e. 1 to 3) However, I need to keep replicates in the same "group" to minimize technical noise for the replicate.